# iOs build failing - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Since yesterday, when I try to make a build for iOs it wont succeed and throw this error:

```js
(node:3043) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at /Users/username/Documents/petpo-fe-mobile-bugs/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:54:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/username/Documents/petpo-fe-mobile-bugs/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:52:44
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/username/Documents/petpo-fe-mobile-bugs/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:50:57
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/username/Documents/petpo-fe-mobile-bugs/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:45:28
    at _fulfilled (/Users/username/Documents/petpo-fe-mobile-bugs/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /Users/username/Documents/petpo-fe-mobile-bugs/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/username/Documents/petpo-fe-mobile-bugs/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
(node:3043) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3043) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've already tried cheking out a new project from git, removing and reinstalling modules, removing and readding the platform in ionic, I don't know what else I could try.
Please, could someone give me some enlightenment on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toLowerCase` is used in **plugins/cordova-plugin-ios-localized-strings/scripts/add_supported_languages.js?**

If yes, there the value is undefined.

Please, try running: `ionic build --prod`

If you face an error -> There is a problem in your code.

If you face no error -> The problem happens when cordova is bundling your app.

If that last option, execute from bash (not cmd): `ionic cordova build ios --prod` or try removing and adding your platform again.

-Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem happens cordova is building my app. I've already tried removing and adding the platform again.
The first problem is in list-emulator-build-targets, line 53, 54.

if (device.name === deviceType.name.replace(/\-inch/g, ' inch') && 
                        device.availability.toLowerCase().indexOf('unavailable') < 0) {
                            availAcc.push(device);
                        }

Comment: @tgomez No problem! But, what version of XCode do you have, lower than 10.1? Update to the latest, please!

Comment: I noticed that this problem started to happen when XCode updated to version 11.0 three days ago.

Comment: Have you tried then to update all packages, remove the ios platform completely and again by adding it?

-remove ios as so:
"ionic cordova platform rm ios"
-re-adding the platform:
"ionic cordova platform add ios@latest"

Comment: Well, thank you very much! Seems that xcode isn't compatible with the platform version we were using. This fixed the issue. By any chance, do u happen to know if we upgrade to the latest version of the ios platform we will lose support for previous ios phones or something? Currently we use version 4.5.4.

Comment: @tgomez Good, dear. However, for the last statement it should not occur, or at least it has not occurred to me with previous APIs with current platforms.

If what can happen is that new bugs of incompatibility are born in the native access because obviously, there are thousands of devices that exist hehe! It's Cross-platform, not the direct SDK.

Comment: "phonegap platform add ios@latest" worked for me too - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I started having this issue too all of a sudden today. Removing and adding the platform did not do it for it. To resolve it, I removed the iOS platform version 4.5.5 and installed the **latest** version of the platform version which seems to fix it.

So do this:

1) Remove the iOS Platform:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
```

2) Install the latest version of iOS Platform:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@latest --save
```

The above installed version 5.0.1 for me. After this, running the command `ionic cordova build ios` did not show any errors.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by going to list-emulator-build-targets:54:45 and removing condition `device.availability.toLowerCase().indexOf('unavailable') < 0` from ***if*** statement.

I was using this workaround before uninstalled second version of XCode.